# Batch printing attachments, with same name, from multiple emails

Tags: vba, printing, outlook, email-attachments

I have emails in Outlook 2013, each with only one file attached called "Report.pdf".

I am trying to batch print all of the attachments from my selection of emails.

I found the below code which works if the attachments all have different names. Is it possible to amend this to print nearly 150 attachments which all have the same name?

The names of the reports don't matter, so feel free to add what you need to them inside the code.

```
Sub BatchPrintAllAttachmentsinMultipleEmails()
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim strTempFolder As String
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objTempFolder As Object
Dim objTempFolderItem As Object
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim DateFormat

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempFolder = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Attachments " & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss")
'Create a new temp folder
MkDir (strTempFolder)

Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

For Each objItem In objSelection
    If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = objItem
       Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments

       'Save all the attachments in the temp folder
       For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
           strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName
           objAttachment.SaveAsFile (strFilePath)

           'Print all the files in the temp folder
           Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
           Set objTempFolder = objShell.NameSpace(0)
           Set objTempFolderItem = objTempFolder.ParseName(strFilePath)
           objTempFolderItem.InvokeVerbEx ("print")
       Next objAttachment
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not say why the code does not work if all the attachments have the same name.  I assume it is because `SaveAsFile` wants to overwrite the last “Report.pdf” with the next “Report.pdf” before printing is finished.

My first thought was to add `Kill strFilePath` before the `SaveAsFile`.  On reflection, I decided that would not work because Shell would still be printing the previous “Report.pdf” when you attempted to delete it.

I think the simplest approach would be:

Add

```
Dim Count as Long
```

to your Dims.

Replace `strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & objAttachment.FileName` by:

```
Count = Count + 1
strFilePath = strTempFolder & "\" & Count & objAttachment.FileName
```

This will create and print files named “1Report.pdf”, “2Report.pdf”, “3Report.pdf” and so on.  I have used a prefix rather than the traditional suffix because it saves the bother of placing `Count` between the file name and the extension.

I assume you have some method of deleting all the attachments from the temporary folder.